# Why is interface default method shadowed by parent private method?

Tags: java, interface, default-method

I don't understand why an IllegalAccessError exception is thrown from the example below. The method `foo()` in `Parent` cannot be inherited by `Child`, because it is private. But trying to call the default method `foo()` leads to the exception.

```
public class Parent {
    private void foo() {
        System.out.println("Parent-foo");
    }
}

interface Boo {
    default void foo() {
        System.out.println("Boo-foo");
    }
}

class Child extends Parent  implements Boo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Child().foo();  // runtime IllegalAccessError;
    }
}
```